# Adding Pact to PATH in Linux

Tags: linux, path, pact

I've gone on both Ubuntu on Virtualbox and on the ubuntu installable for Windows for the sake of installing Pact, but in both versions, it works fine to add the binary and do what this guide says https://github.com/kadena-io/pact#installing-pact with the Binary Distributions instructions, but after marking pact as an executable, I don't know what they mean when they say adding it to my PATH.
I moved the pact binary to `~/bin/` and then did `chmod +x ~/bin/pact` which was the last command that worked. But actually being able to use the Pact REPL or the `$ pact` command keeps not working.
Every time I try to look for answers involving adding things to PATH, it doesn't seem very specific and seems to depend on one's personal setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The PATH is an important concept when working on the command line. It's a list of directories that tell your operating system where to look for programs, so that you can just write `script` instead of `/home/me/bin/script` or `C:\Users\Me\bin\script`

1. Open the `.bashrc` file in your home directory (for example,
   `/home/your-user-name/.bashrc`) in a text editor.
2. Add `export PATH="your-dir:$PATH"` to the last line of the file, where
   *your-dir* is the directory you want to add.
3. Save the `.bashrc` file.
4. Restart your terminal.

Source: https://gist.github.com/nex3/c395b2f8fd4b02068be37c961301caa7#file-path-md

As a `your-dir` you have to put the directory with the `pact` binary inside e.g `~/bin/path` or wherever you have installed the binary.